# Lost access to e-mail account used to register in askubuntu

Tags: support, user-accounts, login, email

I have four e-mails one each in google, microsoft, yahoo and yandex and all four have two step verification using mobile apps enabled. I have registered in my askubuntu account using my yandex e-mail.

I lost my phone and access to previous SIM card. I am using a new SIM card.

I could regain access to my google, microsoft and yahoo accounts. But, unfortunately, I have not been able to regain access to my yandex account.

Although still I am able to access my askubuntu account, if for any reason in future, I need access to my yandex account, I won't be able to do it.

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you cannot just change your log in, I guess one must be active at all times, I don't really know why.

You can however add more [here](http://askubuntu.com/users/mylogins/current), by clicking the add more logins button, then from the same page you can remove the previous one if you wish.

If for some reason, this still does not work, you can contact the SE team [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/contact).

Comment: Thank you, linking the google account worked.

Comment: Also I could remove the old login, thank you